# Using ReportViewer in ASP.NET MVC 5 with .rdlc files stored in project folder

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, report

I need to render a .rdlc reports in a ReportViewer but I don't want to use SQL Server Reporting Services. I want to render my reports from local directory but I can't find proper solution. I've tried this: http://www.nuget.org/packages/MvcReportViewer/
but it works with .rdl not .rdlc files and it needs a report server to work with. I know that I should make an .aspx file with ReportViewer control but what else? Is there a simple solution to render a report from a project path?

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c6524b68-bdfd-4f10-848f-355bc9445323/how-to-dynamically-assign-reportviewer-to-rdlc?forum=vsreportcontrols

Comment: I started down that same path, and there are several changes that can be done to that viewer to get it to work, but there is a major obstacle too. If you are populating your report from objects rather than from a stored proc, like I am, then the viewer cannot seem to receive the data objects. I am considering modifying the lib to grab the objects from a session variable.